# Can you use Quantum Annealing to calculate a Hash collision?

Tags: quantum-computer

I saw in another stack exchange post that the same way quantum annealing can be used to factor primes, it can also be used to calculate a collision in SHA-1 and it references this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209084 .  I understand that the paper claims a technique that can be applied to all NP-hard problems.  Is this true?  And I still don't see how one would apply it to the hash collision problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A link to the other post would be good.

Comment: Btw, note that they only claim to solve all NP problems in polynomial time, not all NP-hard problems. There are problems in NP hard that cannot be reduced to a boolean circuit *at all*, much less in polynomial time.

Comment: Sorry, here it is. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11063/can-quantum-annealing-be-used-for-factorization/39093#39093

Answer (score 0):

Calculating preimages in SHA-1 is in NP, so finding collisions certainly is. So their claim of making all NP problems P would definitely apply. It just becomes a matter of converting the problem into a boolean circuit: basically implement SHA-1 as a circuit and set up gates so the only consistent solution is one with a given hash.

On the other hand, I cannot express in words how skeptical I am of this claim. The authors make many assumptions to show that it is *plausible* that their model relaxes in polynomial time, but fall well short of *demonstrating* that it does. There are too many possible failure modes of their idealized model.