# Quantum annealing computing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

What is Quantum Annealing and quantum annealing computing and what are its advantages and disadvantages with respect to quantum circuit quantum computing/computers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can the D-Wave quantum computer do?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10496/)

Comment: If you get downvotes, it is probably because of [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4598/2751) meta post ...

Comment: Discussion on that meta post is not conclusive, with some arguing that it is an acceptable question. I, for one, would also like to know the answer.